# Why is the callback identifier not being invoked?

Tags: authentication, cakephp, kerberos, cakephp-4.x

I'm trying to implement matching a Kerberos authentication with a local user database in CakePHP4. So I installed CakePHP 4 and the Authentication plugin 2.0. Since Kerberos auth is managed by our IIS WebServer, only thing I have to do is check if the authenticated user is known by my webapp.

The callback authentication should let me implement something like this, right ?
So I put this function in Application.php :

```
<?php
    public function getAuthenticationService(ServerRequestInterface $request): AuthenticationServiceInterface
    {
        $service = new AuthenticationService();
    
        // Define where users should be redirected to when they are not authenticated
        $service->setConfig([
            'unauthenticatedRedirect' => '/users/login',
            'queryParam' => 'redirect',
        ]);
    
        // Load the authenticators. Session should be first.
        $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Session');
    
        $service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Callback', [
            'callback' => function($data) {
                // do identifier logic
                if (empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'])) {
                    return new Result(
                        null,
                        Result::FAILURE_OTHER,
                        ['message' => 'Unknown user.']
                    );
                } else {
                    // On vérifie que l'utilisateur est autorisé à utiliser cette application
                    $users = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Users');
                    $remoteUserNoDomain = str_replace("DOMAIN\\", "", $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']);
    
                    $result = $users->find()
                        ->where(['username' => $remoteUserNoDomain]);
                    
                    if ($result) {
                        return new Result($result, Result::SUCCESS);
                    }
            
                    return new Result(
                        null,
                        Result::FAILURE_OTHER,
                        ['message' => 'Removed user.']
                    );
                }
                
                return null;
            }
        ]);
    
        return $service;
    }
```

But so far, it doesn't seem to work, like it won't call the callback function at all. I tried to put some debug code, exits... Nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you've also done all the other required configuring for authentication to work, ie loading the plugin, adding the authentication middleware, etc.!?

**https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html**

That said, identifiers do not do any work on their own, they are being triggered by authenticators in case they actually require them. You only have the `Session` authenticator loaded, which in its default configuration doesn't make use of identifiers, but even if you configure it to use identifiers (by setting its `identify` option to `true`), it will only use them when there already is an identity in the session, then the identifier is being used to validate that identity.

**https://github.com/cakephp/authentication/blob/2.3.0/src/Authenticator/SessionAuthenticator.php#L52**

I'm not familiar with Kerberos authentication, but if it pre-populates `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` (btw. never access superglobals in CakePHP directly, it will only cause trouble down the road), then what you need is a custom authenticator. You could then re-use the password identifier for the ORM access part, as it allows finding something without checking the password (weirdly enough, given its name).

Quick and dirty example based on your snippet:

```php
// src/Authenticator/KerberosAuthenticator.php

namespace App\Authenticator;

use Authentication\Authenticator\AbstractAuthenticator;
use Authentication\Authenticator\Result;
use Authentication\Authenticator\ResultInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

class KerberosAuthenticator extends AbstractAuthenticator
{
    public function authenticate(ServerRequestInterface $request): ResultInterface
    {
        $server = $request->getServerParams();

        if (empty($server['REMOTE_USER'])) {
            return new Result(null, Result::FAILURE_CREDENTIALS_MISSING);
        }

        $remoteUserNoDomain = str_replace("DOMAIN\\", "", $server['REMOTE_USER']);
        $user = $this->_identifier->identify(['username' => $remoteUserNoDomain]);

        if (empty($user)) {
            return new Result(
                null, 
                Result::FAILURE_IDENTITY_NOT_FOUND, 
                $this->_identifier->getErrors()
            );
        }

        return new Result($user, Result::SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

Your service authenticator/identifier setup would then look like this:

```php
$service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Session');
$service->loadAuthenticator('Kerberos');

$service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password');
```

Nore sure if you'd then really want to use the session authenticator like that though, ie whether you only want to identify the remote user once per session.